# When a word used as tag has a different spelling in American and British English, which spelling should we use?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the case the word used as tag has a different spelling in American and British English, which spelling should we adopt for the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "mother ship" the standard is American spelling for tags.

[What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

While EL&U can buck convention as this isn't a tech topic, I think you should standardize on one or the other. A mix of spellings will look terrible. (Obviously synonyms should be used.)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say go case-by-case: whoever defines the tag gets to decide which spelling to use. If later on we find both spellings in use, we keep the one that's more frequent and mark the other as a synonym.

In other words, do it pretty much how we've been doing it so far. I don't think this is an area where consistency is required, or even very desirable (because whichever spelling we'd choose, we'd snub the users of the other spelling).

Comment: Absolutely. US/UK can honor/honour each other's spelling in the sense of "be respectful towards", rather than "apply consistently".

Comment: I guess that we will never choose as tag a word that in American English has a meaning different from the meaning it has in British English, as in the case of _biscuit_.

Comment: **honor/honour**  You mean, don't use phrases like "execrable americanism"?

Comment: @GEdgar: Tsk. I for one have *never* complained about the [execrable] spelling of the tag **capitalization**, though it does always make me wince! :)